# Webscraping using BS4 - "Length of passed values is 0, index implies 7"

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I get a error of that the length of the of the passed value 0?

This is my code:

```
import bs4 as bs 
import urllib
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

draft2018 ="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_NBA_draft"
draftpage =urllib.request.urlopen(draft2018)
soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(draftpage,"html.parser")

columns = ['Round', 'Pick', 'Player', 'Position',
           'Nationality', 'Team', 'School/club team']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

table = soup.find("table",{"class":"wikitable sortable plainrowheaders"}).tbody

trs = table.find_all("tr")

for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [td.text.replace('\n','') for td in tds]
    df = df.append(pd.Series(row, index=columns), ignore_index=True)
```

Can somebody explain the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to demonstrate the problem, try printing your row:

```
print(row)
```

The first list will print empty and that's why an error is raised. The dataframe expects 7 values but you're providing it zero values. Although Jezrael's solution is more elegant you can make this change so that it works:

```
draft2018 ="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_NBA_draft"
draftpage =urllib.request.urlopen(draft2018)
soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(draftpage,"html.parser")

columns = ['Round', 'Pick', 'Player', 'Position',
           'Nationality', 'Team', 'School/club team']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

table = soup.find("table",{"class":"wikitable sortable plainrowheaders"}).tbody
print(table)
trs = table.find_all("tr")

for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [td.text.replace('\n','') for td in tds]
    if len(row) < 7:
        continue
#     print(row)
    df = df.append(pd.Series(row, index=columns), ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) for return list of DataFrames and select 4. DataFrame by indexing `[3]`, then `rename` columns by dictionary:

```
draft2018 = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_NBA_draft"
d = {'Rnd.':'Round','Pos.':'Position','Nationality[n 1]':'Nationality'}
df = pd.read_html(draft2018)[3].rename(columns=d)
print(df.head())
   Round  Pick             Player Position    Nationality  \
0      1     1      Deandre Ayton        C        Bahamas   
1      1     2  Marvin Bagley III       PF  United States   
2      1     3        Luka Dončić    PG/SF       Slovenia   
3      1     4  Jaren Jackson Jr.       PF  United States   
4      1     5         Trae Young       PG  United States   

                                      Team    School / club team  
0                             Phoenix Suns         Arizona (Fr.)  
1                         Sacramento Kings            Duke (Fr.)  
2      Atlanta Hawks (traded to Dallas)[a]   Real Madrid (Spain)  
3                        Memphis Grizzlies  Michigan State (Fr.)  
4  Dallas Mavericks (traded to Atlanta)[a]        Oklahoma (Fr.)
```

Comment: Why the index [3]?

Comment: @MohitMotwani - it is 4.DataFrame from list of DataFrames

Comment: @MohitMotwani - Exactly.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thank you!